# Partial matching in named lists

Tags: r

I thought that [R](https://www.r-project.org/about.html) did not do partial matching on named lists, so I'm confused by the example below. I tried reading the [Argument matching](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-lang.html#Argument-matching) document but I'm still not sure of what's going on. Any help understanding this example would be appreciated.

```
ll <- list("dir_session" = "some_directory")
print(ll$dir_session) # prints contents of ll$dir_session as expected
print(ll$dir) # prints contents of ll$dir_session, but I expected to print NULL
print(ll[["dir"]]) # prints NULL as expected
```

Not sure if it makes a difference but I'm using R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06).

Comment: Fyi, argument matching refers to, e.g., `ll[["dir", exa = FALSE]]` vs `ll[["dir", exact = FALSE]]` -- it has to do with the `=` and what you write to the left of it in an function call (or leaving the `=` out altogether and letting args be matched by position).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is you thought wrong. It has less to do with the class of object (a named list) and more to do with the "$" operator which does partial matching. See the `?Extract` help page. This is different than argument matching when calling a function.

Comment: Note:  `[[` does partial matching as well, just not by default.